# Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that similarity transformation is reflexive. ie $A=P^{-1}AP $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know a correct answer to this question is to just assume that $P$ is the identity matrix. But, is this argument BELOW correct. $$A=A \Rightarrow AP=AP\Rightarrow A=P^{-1}AP $$

Comment: No, because you right-multiplied the LHS by $P^{-1}$ and left-multiplied the RHS by $P^{-1}$. The correct implication would be $A = APP^{-1}$, which leads us nowhere in the proof.

Comment: If your argument were correct, we'd conclude that  $A=P^{-1}AP$ for **every** invertible matrix $P$ and any matrix $A$. This is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The argument you gave is not correct nor is it an argument. An argument is the use of words plus supporting mathematical expressions that express the steps to the conclusion. You have neither words nor correct mathematical steps.

Here's what the argument should look like. We say a matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix $B$ if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}BP$.

This supposes the question, is $A$ similar to itself? According to the definition, it is similar if we can choose some $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}AP$. In this case, pick $P=I$, the identity matrix, and see that $I^{-1}AI=IAI=AI=A$.